# Predictors for AD/senile dementia dataset

Tags: data-request, medical

I'm looking for some raw datasets about Alzheimer Disease/Senile Dementia.
 
In particular I'd like to investigate the relationship between Physical activity/diet/occupation-education and the occurrence of Alzheimer and Senile Dementia.  Chance of multilevel analysis would be welcomed.
To give some specific exmaples of the kind of research in this field you can look at these papers (I contacted the authors BTW):

[Effect of physical activity on cognitive function in older adults at risk for Alzheimer disease: a randomized trial.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18768414/)

[Rate of memory decline in AD is related to education and occupation: cognitive reserve?](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10599762)

Answer (score 2):

PubMed has a database of author-submitted data that they make available for free, but this is obviously at the discretion of the paper authors.

The data codes are usually listed in the papers themselves, but can also be found here: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sites/GDSbrowser/

To get senile dementia and Alzheimer-specific data, I would advise to search PubMed for more papers about those ailments to get the data codes, and then download them from the PubMed database.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately there are not that many regarding my subjects..

Answer (score 2):

Check out the "Longitudinal Aging Study Amsterdam" [LASA](http://www.lasa-vu.nl/index.htm), perhaps.

[Data availability](http://www.lasa-vu.nl/data/availability_data/availability_data.htm).

Click the "Data" item in the middle of the black menu bar on the page - there's a high-level overview of the data.

I haven't used this dataset, and I haven't requested data from them.

This link is only a pick from my personal list of repositories.